# Black screen on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, display, screen, amd-graphics, toshiba

I've got a fresh install of Lubuntu 16.04 with dual boot. It worked well the first few times I started it but it doesn t work anymore. I get a black screen after selecting the default choice in GRUB. However, if I launch recovery mode, and choose "resume" I get a low definition but otherwise perfect start. Reinstalling Lubuntu soon leads to the same problem, as I tried a few times. I believe some driver in it isn t appropriate or crashes. From a live USB stick, I get full resolution without any problem. Thinking it could be related to the display manager, I installed gdm3 and made it default but it doesn't work either.
What should I do ?
The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite with "AMD A6-3420M APU with Radeon HD graphics"
***EDIT : For some reason, launching with "resume" from recovery doesn't work anymore. I get the login prompt for tty1 on a blinking screen instead.***

Answer (score 0):

[If this doesn't work, I'll remove it]

If it does, then it'll be a dupe FYI.

---

At GRUB boot to recovery mode and drop to a root shell.

1) Mount the file system as R/W: `mount -o remount,rw /`

2) Next, run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

3) Then add `nomodeset` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Becomes:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

And then save by hitting Ctrl+O, then exit nano with Ctrl+X

4) Finally, run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I just did it. I don't get a black screen anymore but I get that screen instead. Any ideas ?

http://i.stack.imgur.com/9HKgr.jpg

looks like I can't embed images because my reputation is too low, here's a link

Comment: @shadok It hangs there?

Comment: And have you installed any drivers for the GPU?

Comment: It's stuck there. I didn't install any driver.